Unable to send data through props in vue js
Context
I had created a product page which populate the products info from API. Now I am building the edit Product page. On edit product page, it contains 4 components which I am rendering through bootstrap-vue tabs components. You can see image and code below:

editProduct.vue
<template>
    <div class="landing-page">
        <div class="titleStyle">
            <span> <i class="bx fw-bold" :class="'bx-arrow-back'" id="btn" @click="$router.go(-1)" /> </span>
            Edit details: {{ item.productName }}
        </div>
        <div class="tableContainer">
            <div class="mt-5">
                <b-tabs content-class="mt-3" fill>
                    <b-tab :title="tabTitles.first" active>
                        <updateCatalog :item="item" />
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab :title="tabTitles.second">
                        <updateDetails :item="item" :changeDetailData="changeDetailData" />
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab :title="tabTitles.third">
                        <changeDetails :item="changeDetailData" />
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab :title="tabTitles.fourth" disabled>
                        <p>I'm a disabled tab!</p>
                    </b-tab>
                </b-tabs>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</template>
<script>

import updateCatalog from '@/components/modal/product/editProductComponent/updateCatalog.vue';
import updateDetails from './editProductComponent/updateDetails.vue';
import changeDetails from '@/components/modal/product/editProductComponent/changeDetails.vue';
import { callAxios } from '@/helper/callAxios';
import { errorToast } from '@/mixins/errorToast';
import { successToast } from '@/mixins/successToast';

export default {
    name: 'edit-product',
    components: {
        updateCatalog,
        updateDetails,
        changeDetails,
    },
    props: ['item'],
    mixins: [errorToast, successToast],
    data() {
        return {
            productObj: this.item,
            tabTitles: {
                first: "Product Catalog Details",
                second: "Update Details",
                third: "Change Details",
                fourth: "Procurement Vendor Update",
            },
            changeDetailData:{},

           
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getGlobalHubId() {
            return this.$store.getters.getMb_hubId;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchChangeDetailData(pid ) {
            const reqData = { query: {resolve: 'hub,vendor,productcatalog'}, body: {}, headers: {} };
            try {
                let res = await callAxios('GET', `products/${pid}/hubs/${this.getGlobalHubId}`, reqData);
                //console.log('res after api call of change page = ', res);
                if (res) {
                    if (res.message) {
                        this.showErrorToast(res.errors[0].message)
                    }
                    else {
                        this.changeDetailData = res.data;
                    }
                    
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during API call:', error);
            }
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        console.log('Item recieved at edit product= ', this.item)
        await this.fetchChangeDetailData(this.item.productId)
    }
}
</script>
<style>

</style>

As you can see I am calling the api here only (inside editProduct.vue) to get the changeDetailData which is used in update Details component as I am passing it through props. Since switching the tabs will not reload the page , so after switching to updateDetails tab, I used watch() to get the changeDetailData which is passed as props in updateDetail.vue. Below is the code
updateDetail.vue
<template>
    <div class="sectionContainer">
        <div class="pt-2 ">
            <div class="accordion w-75 m-auto" role="tablist">
                <!-- acc1 -->
                <b-card no-body>
                    <b-alert show variant="primary">
                        <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="bg-transparent border-bottom-0" role="tab">

                            <span class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <p class="my-auto ps-4">Vendor : {{ item.vendorName }}</p>
                                <b-button block v-b-toggle.accordion-1
                                    variant="primary-outline text-primary fw-bold pe-4">Update</b-button>
                            </span>


                        </b-card-header>

                        <b-collapse id="accordion-1" visible accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
                            <b-card-body>
                                <vendor-detail 
                                :product_id="2"
                                :vendorDetailData="formData" />
                            </b-card-body>
                        </b-collapse>
                    </b-alert>
                </b-card>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>


<script>

import vendorDetail from './updateDetailComponents/vendorDetail.vue';

export default {
    name: 'update-details',
    components: {

        vendorDetail,
        
    },
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        changeDetailData: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            productObj: this.item,
            formData: {},
            
        }
    },
    watch: {
        changeDetailData: {
            handler(newValue) {
                //console.log("WATCH = ", newValue)
                this.formData = newValue;
                console.log("FormData in update = ", this.formData)
            },
            immediate: true
        }
    },
    methods: {

        selectionChanged(selectedOption) {
            console.log(selectedOption);
            this.form.active = selectedOption;
        },      

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Item recieved at update Details = ', this.changeDetailData)
    }
}


<style>


</style>

On entering the updateDetail.vue, I am passing the changeDetailData as formData to vendorDetail component, which is simply a form inside a accordion ( bootstrap component). So again the page does not reload and renders over the same single page

Issue I am facing
Now the issue is that when I come to this vendor detail form and without changing any value , just simply save it. All the fields in the form in the payload remains empty. (ALso I need to edit each fields if I want them to reflect in the payload.)

Below is the code where I had prepopulate the form fields with the data in props but they are coming empty.
vendorDetail.vue
<template>
    <div class="landing-page">
        <div class="formContainer">
            <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset">
                <!-- {{ vendorDetailData.aisleId }} -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <nitrozen-input type="text" label="Vendor" placeholder="Vendor Name" required id="inputField"
                            :value="vendorDetailData?.vendor?.name" @input="onChange('vendorName', $event)"
                            validationMessage="Field is required"  />
                           
                            <div v-if="isFieldEmpty['vendorName']">
                                <validationMessage msg="Vendor is required!" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <nitrozen-dropdown id="active" :items="aisleOptions" label="Aisle" placeholder="Aisle"
                            tooltip="Select Aisle" 
                            v-model="selectedAisle" @change="setAisle" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <nitrozen-input type="text" label="Rack" placeholder="Rack" required id="inputField" :value="vendorDetailData?.rack"
                            @input="onChange('rack', $event)" />
                            <div v-if="isFieldEmpty['rack']">
                                <validationMessage msg="Rack is required!" />
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <nitrozen-input type="text" label="Shelf" placeholder="Shelf" required id="inputField" :value="vendorDetailData?.shelf"
                            @input="onChange('shelf', $event)" />
                            <div v-if="isFieldEmpty['shelf']">
                                <validationMessage msg="Shelf is required!" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="btnContainer">
                    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" class="submitBtn" >Save</b-button>
                </div>

            </b-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

import router from '@/router';
import { NitrozenInput, NitrozenDropdown} from '@gofynd/nitrozen-vue';
import { callAxios } from '@/helper/callAxios';
import validationMessage from '@/components/validationMessage.vue';
import { errorToast } from '@/mixins/errorToast';
import { successToast } from '@/mixins/successToast';

export default {
    name: 'vendor-detail',
    components: {
        NitrozenInput,
        NitrozenDropdown,
        validationMessage
    },
    props: {
        vendorDetailData: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },

        product_id : {
            type : Number,
            required : true,
        }
    },
    mixins:[errorToast,successToast],
    data() {
        return {
            item: {},
            aisleListData : [],
            form: {
                vendorId: this.vendorDetailData?.vendor?.id,  //these values comes empty
                aisleId: this.vendorDetailData?.aisleId,  //these values comes empty
                rack: this.vendorDetailData?.rack,  //these values comes empty
                shelf: this.vendorDetailData?.shelf,   //these values comes empty
            },
            aisleOptions: [],
            selectedAisle: this.vendorDetailData?.aisleId,  //these values comes empty
            aisleList: [
                {
                    "createdOn": "2019-05-01 13:25:29",
                    "createdBy": -3,
                    "modifiedOn": "2019-05-01 13:25:29",
                    "modifiedBy": -3,
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "A4",
                    "sortOrder": 0
                },
                {
                    "createdOn": "2019-05-01 13:25:29",
                    "createdBy": -3,
                    "modifiedOn": "2019-05-01 13:25:29",
                    "modifiedBy": -3,
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "A5",
                    "sortOrder": 0
                },
                
            ], 
            isFieldEmpty:{vendorName:false,rack:false,shelf:false},
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getGlobalHubId() {
            return this.$store.getters.getMb_hubId;
        },
        getCompanyId() {
            return this.$store.getters.getCompanyId;
        }
    },

    methods: {
        async onSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            this.form.vendorId = this.vendorDetailData.vendor.id;
            

            //This comes empty
            alert("API PAYLAOD = ",JSON.stringify(this.form))
            const payload = this.form;
            const reqData = { query: {}, body: payload, headers: {} };
            try {
                let res = await callAxios('PATCH', `products/${this.product_id}/hubs/${this.getGlobalHubId}/vendor`, reqData);
                
                if (res) {
                    if (res.message) {
                        this.showErrorToast(res.errors[0].message)
                    }
                    else {
                        this.showSuccessToast('Vendor Details Updated');
                        router.push(`company/${this.getCompanyId}/product`)
                    }
                    
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during API call:', error);
            }
        },
        onReset(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            this.show = false
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.show = true
            })
        },
        onChange(field, event) {
            
            this.isFieldEmpty[field] = event.length == 0 ? true:false;
            this.form[field] = event;
        },
        setAisle(selectedAisle) {
            console.log(selectedAisle);
            this.form.aisleId = selectedAisle;
        },
        createAisleOptions() {
            this.aisleOptions = this.aisleList.map(ele => ({ text: ele.name, value: ele.id }));
        },
        



    },
    mounted() {
        this.createAisleOptions();
   
        console.log('Item recieved vendor component= ', this.vendorDetailData)
        
    }
}
</script>
<style>

</style>

Please help me in this issue.( I know its a long explanation )  , I want that payload and all the values which coming empty should get prepopulated :<
form: {
                vendorId: this.vendorDetailData?.vendor?.id,  //these values comes empty
                aisleId: this.vendorDetailData?.aisleId,  //these values comes empty
                rack: this.vendorDetailData?.rack,  //these values comes empty
                shelf: this.vendorDetailData?.shelf,   //these values comes empty
            },

